# javascript import issues with import vs require

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, electron

I am building a desktop application using [Electorn](https://electronjs.org) and angular 8. I am trying to import a javascript file in `index.html` which has content like the following.

```
import ipcRenderer from 'electron';

import {
    START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE,
    NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_STARTED,
    NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_ERROR,
    NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED,
    TOKEN_UPDATED,
} from 'electron-push-receiver/src/constants';
```

So when I use the above code I get error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

and When I use following code I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

```
 const { ipcRenderer } = require ('electron')
 const {
     START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE,
     NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_STARTED,
     NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_ERROR,
     NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED,
     TOKEN_UPDATED,
 } = require ('electron-push-receiver/src/constants')
```

What could be the solution?

All the angular imports work with first snippets above. they do not have `require`. So I am assuming the first snippet should work as I am importing it in angular.

I am importing the file by specifying the following in the angular.json file.

```
"scripts": [
              "../path/to/.js",
            ]
```

Comment: `import` works with ES6 modules. Do you have your app's script tag type set to module like so: `<script type="module" src="...">` ? Or does angular do that for you automatically? Without this, import won't work. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Are you getting `Unexpected identifier` for `import`? And `require` is node specific as well as if you are using requirejs module laoder.

Comment: angular may be doing it automatically @user95227, as other imports in `ts` files work.

Comment: @ambianBeing when I use import I get `Unexpected Identifier` but I am not sure which exact identifier is.

Comment: The unexpected identifier is `import` probably

Comment: @ambianBeing I think yes, for `import` only. I kept a single import statement and still get the same issue.

Comment: Does `electron` directly supports `ES6 module system import/export` without some transpilation tool ..I am not sure? Also this `import ipcRenderer from 'electron';` should be this `import {ipcRenderer} from "electron";` unless that's `default` export. Try it out.

Comment: @ambianBeing I tried both and specified what I get in my question. Another thing is I am importing this file in an angular app, so ES6 should work.

Answer (score 1):

For that import for the ipcRenderer to work you have to establish it like so:

```
import { ipcRenderer } from "electron";
```

`ipcRenderer` being a module that you are pulling out of the `electron` library.